# Must be a simple jquery error?

Tags: jquery

Still have no luck with this jquery for a on click menu script. I studied the attr setting but we no luck in making it function.

Do I need to load the script in the body with onload?

I have a simple script that works but you have to click the menu to open and close with no fancy slide :(

**--jquery--**

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#top_menu_menub').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var ulId = $this.attr("#topmenu");
            var clicked_menu_is_visible = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId).filter(':visible').length > 0;
            var visible_uls = $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible');
            if (visible_uls.length === 0) { 
                //no menus showing - just show clicked menu 
                $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                $ul.slideToggle('medium');
            }
            else { 
                //close open menus (should only be one open) then open clicked menu
                //via callback 
                $this.parent().find("ul").filter(':visible').slideUp("medium", function() {
                    $ul = $this.parent().find("ul" + ulId);
                    //open clicked menu - unless menu was already open when clicked
                    if (!clicked_menu_is_visible) {
                        $ul.slideToggle('medium');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**--- css --**

```
#top_menu_menub {
    padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #aaa;
    background-image: url(../images/apecbuttona.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 8px 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#topmenu {list-style-type:none; width:200px; padding:0; margin:0 auto; height: 24px;}
#topmenu ul {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0; border: solid 1px #eee; border-radius: 5px; }
#topmenu li {float:left; margin:1px 1px 0 0;position:relative; z-index: 9999}
#topmenu li.sub {width: 200px; height: 16px; padding: 1px 0px 0px 0px;}
#topmenu li.sub:hover { color:#00CCFF; background-image: url(../images/apecbutton.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: 8px 0px; height: 24px;}
#topmenu li a {display:block; color:#999; font-family:arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px; line-height:23px; width:107px; text-decoration:none; text-align:left; cursor:pointer; font-weight:100; border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; padding-left: 8px;}
#topmenu li a:hover {background:#fff; color:#4FA4F9;}
#topmenu ul {position:absolute;left:-9800px;width:115px; }
#topmenu li.click {}
#topmenu li.click ul{left: 12px; top:22px; background: #fff; }
```

**---html---**

```
<div id="top_menu_menub">
    <ul id="topmenu">
        <li class="sub">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">11111111</a></li>
                <li><a href="">22222222</a></li>
                <li><a href="">33333333</a></li>
                <li><a href="">44444444</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update your question to explain clearly (a) what is supposed to happen, and (b) what actually happens. (Consider providing a demo at http://jsfiddle.net) _"do i need to load the script in the body with onload??"_ No. You've already got _two_ document.ready handlers, one inside the other that provide an equivalent to onload. (`$(function(){...})` is equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){...})` - you don't need both.)

Comment: is it ok to do the hover function for the background image to click in css? (jquery search's for div to click so shouldn't matter?)

Comment: on clicking the div which has a background image hover in css a ul menu should appear below the div with a slide style. once the mouse leaves it slides up.

Comment: thats what i thought, i think its got something to do with var ulId = $this.attr("topmenu"); or  $('div#top_menu_menub').click(function (e) {

Answer (score 1):

this line make no sense:

```
var ulId = $this.attr("topmenu");
```

also

```
find("ul" + ulId)
```

in HTML you have :

```
<ul id="topmenu">
```

i think you have to **redo the script**

Comment: This makes better sense as top_men_menub is the target div and topmenu is the ul id... updated above this works when using span or a href as a target but not with div??? should i add another div and toggle between the two instead?

Comment: @DavidWalter the html is correct the issue you have is jquery script

Comment: yeah just not getting it have studied. i understand setting the function to pick up the element, then setting the varibles for the code then toggling it seems fine and if i create a "ahref instead it works. ive used other peoples code to try and generate result that doesnt work eithier.wouldnt kno what to code next a toggle div function?